# How to use Lisp in Android?

Tags: android, lisp

How I can use a  Lisp library in Android (Eclipse Java)?

For example I like have a "Intelligent apps" with Lisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need or common lisp implementation, which can run under android, or some tool to compile common lisp code into JVM Bytecode or native library for android (with NDK). As far as I know, there is no good and free solution for this problem for now.

[Clozure Common Lisp](http://ccl.clozure.com/) can run under android, but you can't really create an application which can be published in play store with it. Or it'll be very difficult. There is even [an example](https://github.com/fukamachi/clozure-cl/blob/master/examples/android/native-activity.lisp) for CCL on android.

There is also proprietary Common Lisp implementation from wukix - [MOCL](https://wukix.com/mocl), which aims to be able to bring Common Lisp into mobile development world. I had no experience with that, you can give it a try.

As I said, looks like for now there is no easy way to do what you want.

Comment: Gary Byers wrote two weeks ago: *CCL has worked (for various values of "work") on various versions of Android at various times.  It has never really been actively developed oe maintained, and I don't think that anyone has done anything with it in a year or so.*

Comment: @RainerJoswig, looks like complete right description of a current situation. As I sad - ok for play with it maybe, but absolutely not ready for real world applications.

Answer (score 3):

Try lispworks android/ios runtime:
Sad thing it's not free, but you can ask for evaluation license.

Useful links:

[Build iOS/Android Libraries in Common Lisp with LispWorks](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/05/lispworks-mobile-runtime)

[LispWorks® for Mobile Runtime](http://www.lispworks.com/products/lw4mr.html)

[LispWorks User Guide and Reference Manual- 16 Android interface](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/LW/html/lw-119.htm)

Mocl is another alternative:

[mocl (+ lisp ios android osx)](https://wukix.com/mocl)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [eql5-android](https://gitlab.com/eql/EQL5-Android), which integrates QML for the UI. It features a few examples.

Answer (score 3):

[LambdaNative](http://www.lambdanative.org/) is technically a lisp (it is an implementation of Scheme based on Gambit-C Scheme) which implements its own GUI and various other modules.

It uses the same source code to create native applications for Android, iOS, Linux, Mac OS X, Blackberry 10, Windows, OpenBSD and OpenWrt.